# plugging in a USB device resets keyboard layout

Tags: usb, arch-linux, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

I'm using Manjaro Linux with the Cinnamon desktop.

I chose English as system language during the installation and set the keyboard layout afterwards to another language.

Every time I plug in a USB device, the keyboard layout is reset to English.

Do you have any idea how I could permanently set the keyboard layout without losing English as system language?

Comment: Since you have already found a solution, please consider adding it as an answer. You will also be able to mark it as accepted to help other users who might stumble into the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Cinnamon System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Input Sources